# What does it mean to ground in this context?

Tags: electrostatics, potential, voltage, short-circuits

This is a homework problem that I already submitted, but am still unsure about.

I am consider the following situation, re we have a conducting sphere of radius $R$ with charge $q$, which is surrounded by a thick metal shell of inner radius $r_1$ and outer radius $r_2$. So $R<r_1<r_2$. Let's set the potential at infinity to be $0$.

I am now told that the outer shell (at $r_2$) is "grounded," which apparently means that the outer shell now has potential equal to $0$, the same as that at infinity.

But what is happening here? It seems clear to me that one way to make this happen is to have the charge on the outer surface at $b$ to be $0$, and then indeed by some type of "shielding", the potential would indeed be at $0$.

However, this seems like an ad-hoc explanation; what is the grounding actually doing, physically, and how can it just "set" the potential to be zero? I heard it has to do with being a large charge sink, but I'm not sure how to reconcile this relationship between charge and potential, and how the outer shell can just become the same as that of infinity.

Comment: You can choose any potential you want to be your reference which is the same as saying you can choose any potential to be "zero". But by choosing the infinite charge to be your reference means that it won't change relative to other things if charge is injected; You'll have a meter stick that doesn't change length, so to speak. So if everything else simultaneously gets more positive by the same amount, then you know that everything actually got more positive and it's not that your reference just got more negative.

Comment: @DKNguyen I get that I can choose arbitrarily the values of potential, but what is happening when we "ground" the outer shell to set the potential there equal to zero, the potential at infinity?

Comment: Grounding the shell causes it to "inherit" the potential and infinite charge sink property of the Earth which is really your reference. "*The same as that at infinity*" reads to me as "*the same potential energy at infinite so not just locally, but universally, zero.*" That's how I'm reading it, at least. So a little redundant in most contexts. For example, maybe you are on an aircraft carrier which is a near-infinite charge sink so you use that as your reference. But the carrier might be at a different potential than the Earth which is even more of a near-infinite charge sink. Awkward wording

Answer (score 0):

> I am now told that the outer shell (at $r_2$) is "grounded," which
> apparently means that the outer shell now has potential equal to $0$,
> the same as that at infinity.

You can't assign multiple points to be zero potential. You didn't say what the problem asks for, but as long as you are only interested in the potential difference between two points, it doesn't matter where you assign the potential to be zero. Technically, it's totally arbitrary. But sometimes the selection makes it easier to solve the problem.

Hope this helps.